# How do I add fields and hide them from client?

Tags: entities, users

I added fields to a Client profile using Profile2, such as first name and last name. But I added another fields, let's call it "Assigned Consultant".

But the "Assigned Consultant" field...

- I don't want it to be available on registration
- I don't want it to be available on the Client view user profile page
- I don't want it to be available on the Client edit user profile page

I just want the "Assigned Consultant" field to be available to Administrator users.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Field permissions module would probably be the way. https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

"The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity."

Check the issue queue though, for example:
https://drupal.org/node/2069281, "Profile2 field is empty after profile is saved"

Answer (score 0):

To prevent display on the view user profile page, you should be able to field display options and move the field to hidden.

For the registration page, I'm sure there are some options in Profile2 to control if it appears on the registration page.

To hide it on the edit page for non-administrators, you can use the `#access` key on the form array.

You change this using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9.0.x).

For example, in a custom module or your theme:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'id_of_the_edit_form') {
    // Get the user role.
    $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();

    // If the role does not include administrator.
    if(!in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
      // Set the field access to FALSE.
      $form['field_assigned_consultant']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```